# Original image wordpress in regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

Ok, I would like to detect, using the .htaccess file, if the original version of an image is being requested by wordpress.  I will then send the request to a specific php file to make some alterations to the file.

The file names for the images are as follows

```
/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background-1000x200.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background-1500x350.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background-1600x400.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background-1600x600.jpg
```

I would like to detect the original image, without the size parameters.

I have tried:
`(?<!-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4})\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$` but for some reason it isn't working.  Could anybody help me with why?

I am trying to do the following:

- `\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$` looks for .jpg, .jpeg, .gif or .png at the end of a line
- I then do a negative lookbehind so that it isn't preceded by -[numbers]x[numbers] where the numbers should be able to be anything between 0 and 9999.

I think this is because I can't have the quantifiers in a negative lookahead but I can't think of another way to accomplish this.

I can't guarantee that the file name won't end in a number so just checking for a number won't work.  I will also probably have image sizes that aren't 4 digits then 3 digits so checking for that isn't possible either.

Thank you in advance, anybody who has take the time to read this

Comment: Maybe [`^(?!.*-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}).*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$`](https://regex101.com/r/sO4vM1/2) will help.

Comment: Thank you, that works.  Could you explain why that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match the whole string only if it does not contain your resolution pattern.

```
^(?!.*-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}).*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO4vM1/2)

It matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4})` - there should be no `-`, 1 to 4 digits, `x`, 1 to 4 digits after any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols (`.*`)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols as many as possible up to the
- `\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)` - a literal dot followed with either `jpg`, `jpeg`, etc.
- `$` - end of string.

Add `(...)` capturing groups where necessary to re-use the captured value in the replacement with backreferences.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I can see why your solution works but I am still unsure why mine didn't.  I thought it was because I couldn't use quantifiers in a lookbehind but clearly you can because you do in your solution.

Comment: You used the quantifiers of unknown length in a *lookbehind*, I am using them in the *lookahead*. You can use patterns of any width in lookaheads in every regex flavor that supports lookaheads.